# Two-way database synchronization

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

How can I do two-way synchronization? In my desktop application, I have implemented synchronization, but I can't do it two-way.

E.g.,
I have 2 fields (`Name`, `Phone Number`) on the form. From a system with a local database, I have updated `Name`, and from another system with a server database, I have updated `Phone Number`.

Now, if I am doing synchronization, I want both changes in both databases, but I am getting only the last change done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync Framework tracks changes at the row level, not at the column level. it doesn't know which column was change, only that a row has changed.

you're scenario results in an update - update conflict. When you resolve a conflict, you specify the winning row. Sync Fx will not merge changes on different columns. e.g., it will not merge the name and phone number from both change.

its either the source or the destination row wins.

Comment: Ok, I have the same problem. Do you have any other solution for the scenario I explained?